# Mac OS X finder requiring permissions when deleting file, even after chmod

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, python, finder

I created a Python script that requires `sudo` permissions to run (doing ICMP requests). This script creates a small directory and a couple `.csv` files, as well as a `log.txt` file. At first, after running the program, I was able to delete the artifacts after running to test directory and file creation.

Now, all of a sudden, OS X Finder is asking me for permissions to delete the directory and log file. I performed a `chmod 775 *` on the directory I have my module in and deleted the folder and file as necessary. However, after running the script again, it requires me to fulfill permissions yet again. Another `chmod`, I can delete the files and folders. However, every time I run the program I run into the same issue.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this permanently?

Comment: Put the chmod command into the python script?

Comment: I could, but that sounds risky. Why is this happening in the first place?

Comment: A brief `sudo mkdir foobar` test gives me the same results, *in the Finder*.  I can actually delete it from the Terminal without being prompted, but the Finder prompts me.  The Terminal could be because I just did the `sudo` (but that's not my understanding of sudo privileges) or it could be because I'm in the same group (staff) as root.

Comment: I think that's probably the problem. My python code has to be run with sudo privileges because it's running ICMP commands and then it creates those files and folders, which is probably being done under those sudo privvies. I wonder if there's a way to "unsudo" in my script after I do the ICMP command.

Comment: Yes, the new folder/files are owned by root, not "you".  Since you're running under `sudo`, though, you could use a command like `chown` to make you the own of the folder/files again, then you could delete in the Finder without getting a prompt.  So, I think adding a `chown` or a `chmod` in the Python script should do the trick!

Comment: BTW, I've been thinking that the reason for the "sudden change" may have been Mavericks.  In my testing, I found no issue deleting from the Terminal, so the user (me) definitely had the permissions needed to delete the files.  But, the Finder may have noticed that "root" owned the folder/files and presented an additional prompt.  This could be new behavior in Mavericks.  If any of these ideas solve or work-around the issue for you, I'll write up an official Answer below that hopefully you'll Accept.

Comment: Yeah go ahead. Try to be as verbose as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above between the op and me, the root cause of the permission problem is that the folder/files created in the Python script are owned by root, not the op's user account.  Anything created while running `sudo` will be owned by root.

Workarounds for this are to include a `chmod` or `chown` command in the script, giving the op's user account permission to delete the file/folder.  I recommend `chown`, as it's possible that the Finder (in Mavericks) is detecting that root is the owner and prompting the user.  This happens to me even when my account has full permissions (through the group permissions).  Finder could be putting an extra level of protection on root-owned files.  Using `chown` in the script should set everything right for Terminal and Finder!

Comment: Dang, it won't let me vote it up until I have 15 rep tho. However, I was still able to accept as best answer. Perhaps you can vote up my question so I have more reputation and I'll pass it along :)